# kendo-grid directive without header row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

Does [Kendo UI - Grid / AngularJS](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular) support a grid without header row  ?

Mean to get  -

[image]

instead of  -

[image]

If so , how does its `options` should look like ?

(I'm looking for 100% Kendo UI API solution , any other hacking I can do it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you consider this a 100% KendoUI solution, but on **[dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound)**, you could hide the **[thead field](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-thead)**

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  e.sender.thead.hide();
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IjUQu)**